# When starting a New game scene in swift the image distorts

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I am having trouble keeping a constant scene dimension when transitioning to a new scene. The new scene is slightly compressed when it is presented.

My GameSceneController is the default code and looks like so:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
  }
```

When I change the scene to subviews like so:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

  if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
    // Configure the view.
    var skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    skView.presentScene(scene)

  }
}
```

It corrects the problem, but then I lose the original dimension of my controller and the image is zoomed in.